# Is `host.name.edu:XXXX` an invalid format for an `.ssh/config` file?

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-config

I have weird case where I'm being told my IT to use the port inside the ssh URL to connect to a git server. My original ssh config is the following:

```
Host my-host-alias
  HostName redacted.redacted.edu
  Port 2222
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-ssh-private-key
```

and I was using the git remote url `ssh://git@my-host-alias/path/to/repo.git`. I was getting some weird Auth errors with that config (though basic functionality was still working) so IT instructed me to use the git remote url `ssh://git@redacted.redacted.edu:2222/path/to/repo.git` and that appeared to work with a manually specified `GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i ~/.ssh/my-private-ssh-key`. So I reconfigured my .ssh/config as follows:

```
Host redacted.redacted.edu:2222
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-ssh-private-key
```

Suddenly, it seems as if ssh can't parse the Host entry anymore. If I run `ssh -Tvvv ssh://git@redacted.redacted.edu` I get the following output (snippet):

```
debug1: /Users/myuser/.ssh/config line 94: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Applying options for *
```

It appears that specifying a Host with a port in the URL breaks the parsing of .ssh/config. Can someone verify this?

Comment: Your first config looks good to me. I don't know what `weird Auth
errors` you were getting because you didn't specify them.  And you
don't them to pass username manually: `git clone
my-host-alias:path/to/repo.git` should be enough.

Comment: Yes, `host:port` is the wrong format for a `Host` line in an ssh config.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk the auth errors turned out to be unrelated to the .ssh/config issue. There isn't any issue with specifying the user explicitly, though I suspect it gets overridden by the config file if `User` is present.

Comment: @torek could you point me to where in the openssh documentation there is such a constraint on the format?

Comment: `I suspect it gets overridden by the config file if User` - whatever you type on the command line takes precedence. But as you already specified user in the config you don't need to do that again on the command line.

Comment: It's not a constraint. That is, it's not that it's *syntactically* wrong. It's that when ssh goes to look for the line, it uses only the *host name*. So if you use `ssh user@host:port command ...` or in this case `ssh://user@host:port/path/to/repo.git`, ssh only looks for `Host host`, not `Host host:port`; the string `host:port` won't match the string `host` and ssh will move on to the next configuration entry.

Answer (score 0):

The [SSH URI syntax](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-scp-sftp-ssh-uri-04#section-3.3) won't use `~/.ssh/config`

The [SCP syntax](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php) used by [OpenSSH (1999)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSH), from the [history of the SSH protocol](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/#sec-History-of-the-SSH-protocol), *predates* [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) (finalized with [RFC 3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt), January 2005)

So you need to use `my-host-alias:path/to/repo.git` if you want to use `.ssh/config`.